# Rider can't resolve nameof(OtherClass.Method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rider

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new .NET Core Web API project
- Head over to the generated `WeatherForecastController`, update the class to

  ```
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
  {
      [HttpGet("{id}")]
      public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetById(int id)
      {
          return Ok(null);
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a second controller

  ```
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class FooController : ControllerBase
  {
      [HttpPost]
      public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Create()
      {
          return CreatedAtAction(nameof(WeatherForecastController.GetById), new { id = 1 }, null);
      }
  }
  ```
- Build be project, it should be fine
- Rider comes up with an error at the `Create` route

  > Cannot resolve action 'GetById'

As you can see here

[image]

This is annoying because the IDE comes up with it in the project explorer too

[image]

Although the code works fine. So is my code bad and I should improve it? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong overload of `CreatedAtAction` is being used.

It cannot resolve action `GetById` because the overload used expects the action to belong to the current controller (ie `FooController`).

If the intended action belongs to another controller then the controller name needs to be included.

*FooController:*

```
//...

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<object> Create() {
    return CreatedAtAction(
        actionName: "GetById",
        controllerName: "WeatherForecast", //Note removal of `Controller` suffix
        routeValues: new { id = 1 }, 
        value: null);
}

//...
```

Reference [ControllerBase.CreatedAtAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction)

Comment: thanks for your reply. That didn't fix the problem, even when using hardcoded strings like `CreatedAtAction("GetProductByIdAsync", "ProductsController", new { id = 1 }, product);` Rider says it's not able to resolve the method and controller name.

Comment: Like so https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/165027329981153280/719160075184242758/unknown.png or so https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/165027329981153280/719160496791748619/unknown.png

Comment: @Question3r those links do not work for me. I am getting an access denied message

Comment: @Question3r based on that last image, `controllerName` should be `Products` (without the `Controller` suffix)

Comment: Ok so this seems to work `return CreatedAtAction(nameof(ProductsController.GetProductByIdAsync), "Products", new { id = 1 }, product);` Is there any way I don't have to hardcode "Products"? Like removing the suffix via `nameof(ProductsController).RemoveSuffix()`

Comment: Ok it seems this works too `nameof(Products)`. I don't know why, but the build works ...

Comment: @Question3r That could be just luck. Do you have a `Products` class?

Comment: no `Products` is the namespace. But when I hover over it it knows the Controller `(class) API.Products.ProductsController` and when hitting F12 to go to that class it jumps to the controller

Comment: @Question3r well then that is new to me. But I guess it is probably some feature of Rider. That does not happen in VS.

Comment: hmm .. tested it with multiple endpoints relying on the same problem and it works. And when firing the request in Postman I get a 201. When analyzing the headers the `Location` field has a correct URL route

Comment: i had this problem this morning. Typing the parameter name `actionName:` followed by `""` then gave me a suggested list of actions. In my case, the `Async` on the end of the names was being dropped